# Creating a local projection system in QGIS using Proj.4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm trying to recreate a local mine grid for the QGIS users within our group. This grid is a modification of the Northing (-8000000).

I imported the original UTM zone (35S).

[image: Point in original Space]

What is the function in Proj.4 to just change the Y value?

I tried using the y_0 function to no avail.

I'm wondering if there's another option (outside of Proj.4) to do this, if there's any suggestions of how to do this, I'd be happy to try those too.

Answer (score 1):

UTM is a special case of transverse mercator, where the central meridian is derived from the zone number, and the false Easting is set to 500 km from that.

For a custom CRS, you have to specify lon_0, x_0 and y_0 manually:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000. +y_0=-8000000. +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```